# Сохранение массива значений в базу данных yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, activerecord

Скорее решение, т.к. сам не смог нигде найти ответ.

Столкнулся с проблемой - **yii2 сохраняет последнее значение с помощью цикла**.
Код контроллера выглядел так:

```
$userCategories = new UserCategory();
foreach ($model->user_category as $item) {
                    $userCategories->user_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->getId();
                    $userCategories->category_id = intval($item);
                    $userCategories->save(false);
                }
```

из-за чего в базу сохранялось последнее значение цикла.
Решение выглядит просто. Необходимо определять вызов новой модели в теле цикла, тогда все значения массива будут сохранены:

```
foreach ($model->user_category as $item) {
                    $userCategories = new UserCategory(); /*  вот здесь */
                    $userCategories->user_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->getId();
                    $userCategories->category_id = intval($item);
                    $userCategories->save(false);
                }
```

Привожу снимок полученных записей в БД:

[image: Скриншот сохраненных записей в БД]

Comment: спасибо, Кэп. В первый проход цикла новая запись создалась, в каждый последующий в ней уже менялись значения и перезаписывались. Это крайне нормальное поведение для большинства ORM

Comment: Это норма. Вы же каждый цикл не создаёте новую модель, которая является **отражением строки в базе данных**, поэтому и перезаписывается уже существующая модель.  Можно пробовать ставить `$userCategories->isNewRecord = true;`. Но в целом достаточно создавать новую модель в цикле, повышеуказанной причине